# What is the performance penalty to using lazy val in scala, but INSIDE a def

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I know inside a class using lazy val uses some type of double lock pattern.  But what about inside a function definition?  Does it use the same pattern?

For example:

```
class Sample {
  def computation(): Something = {}

  def fn(compute: Boolean, default: Something): Something = {
    lazy val c = computation()

    if (compute) c*c else default
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes it uses the same pattern. See your Scala-code:

```
class Sample {
  def computation(): Int = 100

  def fn(compute: Boolean, default: Int): Int = {
    lazy val c = computation()

    if (compute) c*c else default
  }
}
```

compiled with scalac and decompiled with jad:

```
public class Sample implements ScalaObject
{

    public int computation()
    {
        return 100;
    }

    public int fn(boolean compute, int default)
    {
        VolatileIntRef bitmap$0$1 = new VolatileIntRef(0);
        IntRef c$lzy$1 = new IntRef(0);
        return compute ? c$1(c$lzy$1, bitmap$0$1) * c$1(c$lzy$1, bitmap$0$1) : default;
    }

    private final int c$1(IntRef intref, VolatileIntRef volatileintref)
    {
        if((volatileintref.elem & 1) == 0)
            synchronized(this)
            {
                if((volatileintref.elem & 1) == 0)
                {
                    intref.elem = computation();
                    volatileintref.elem = volatileintref.elem | 1;
                }
                BoxedUnit _tmp = BoxedUnit.UNIT;
            }
        return intref.elem;
    }

    public Sample()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: According to Java Concurrency in Practice, use of DCL is discouraged (at best, it's useless; at worst, it's broken). What's the benefit here?

Comment: @NoelYap: I don't know why it is done this way. Feel free to ask this as an own question...

Comment: @sschaef, there's a comment in a similar post that says that DCL is no longer used.

Comment: @NoelYap: Yes, I heard that, too. But when I look to the bytecode I still see the DCL.

Comment: With the update of the Java Memory Model in Java5, DCL behaves as expected, IF the variable is made `volatile`.